# Responsive Grid with 100% w&h and no margin/padding

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been looking for a CSS grid with 100% width and height and no margin/padding on the borders (I want some element to stick on the left and right of the browser window when I'm in regular desktop mode). I can't seem to find one that suits my need: I checked out bootrstrap but it seems way too complicated because I only have to make a simple landing page

Comment: Hi, please post your code and as a question based on an issue you are having. posts requesting people opinions or recommendations generally get knocked down/closed

Comment: check out schema: http://danmalarkey.github.io/schema/index.html

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Throwing up the code for your entire website doesn't help. Do you have a sample of your grid CSS?

Comment: I don't have one, I can put the css and html structure that I made by hand, but I didn't use any CSS grid to build the page, I think that's why I'm stucked now.

Comment: what is it about your css so far that you think is 'buggy'?

Comment: For example, some elements move when I resize the page, some others don't, like the quote: it's just stucked at the center of the page.

Also, when I resize it's gets really messy, all the components mesh up and pile on one another. And.. maybe its just me, but I'm not really skilled so I positioned most of the elements using negative margin which I think is not the ideal way

Comment: The simple fact is that most responsive grids are similar, and most can be made to do what you're describing. The concepts you need to learn to implement them are fairly universal. To eliminate gutters on almost any grid, simply apply a negative margin to the inner element that matches the grid's gutters.

Comment: Demo: I've removed padding on Bootstrap's columns and added borders for visualization. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/23jyv33k You could do this with almost any free and open-source responsive grid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic format you can use, with some quick CSS/HTML examples. Hope this helps.

In your body, you can apply the .sectional class to any element you want. Be sure to give your contents inside anything with the .sectional class appropriate margin/padding. Use the classes for colors by using any that are color names as background-colors and any with 'fc' as font-coloring.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<meta charset="utf-8">


<title>Example - full width</title>


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">


<style>

*, html, body           {box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
body                    {width:100%; height:100%; margin:0em auto; font-size:100%;}
.sectional              {margin:0px; padding:0em 0em 0em 0em; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}


.black                  {background-color:#000000!important;}
.black-fc               {color:#000000;}
.blue                   {background-color:#0000FF; }
.blue-fc                {color:#0000FF; }
.coral                  {background-color:#FF7F50; }
.coral-fc               {color:#FF7F50; }
.dark-gray              {background-color:#505050!important;}
.dark-gray-fc           {color:#505050;}
.gainsboro              {background-color:#DCDCDC!important;}
.gainsboro-fc           {color:#DCDCDC;}
.midnight               {background-color:#252525!important;}
.midnight-fc            {color:#252525;}
.scarpa-flow            {background-color:#E8E8ED!important;}
.scarpa-flow-fc         {color:#E8E8ED;}
.soft-blueberry         {background-color:#BCC6CF!important;}
.soft-blueberry-fc      {color:#BCC6CF;}
.tomato                 {background-color:#FF6347!important;}
.tomato-fc              {color:#FF6347;}
.white                  {background-color:#FFFFFF!important;}
.white-fc               {color:#FFFFFF;}


.inside                 {width:97%;margin:0em 1.5% 0em 1.5%;}

.align-left             {text-align:left;}
.align-right            {text-align:right;}
.align-center           {text-align:center;}

.pad-vertical           {padding-top:3em;padding-bottom:3em;}

</style>

</head>
<body>



<main class="sectional dark-gray">
  <div class="inside white-fc">
  <h1 class="scarpa-flow-fc">This is some text.</h1>
  <p>This is some paragraph text...</p>
  <p class="coral-fc">This is some more text...</p>
  </div>
</main>


<section class="sectional align-center scarpa-flow">
  <div class="inside midnight-fc">
  <h1 class="blue-fc">This is some text.</h1>
  <p>This is some paragraph text...</p>
  <p class="tomato-fc">This is some more text...</p>
  </div>
</section>


<h2 class="sectional pad-vertical midnight soft-blueberry-fc"><span class="inside">A Section Heading</span></h2>



</body>
</html>
```